# Flutter Problem With Changing Text After Hitting A Button

Tags: flutter

I'm a beginner and wanted to make a quick app where it shows how many times you have hit a button and later translate this knowledge of button interaction to making a calculator. I wrote some code but do not know what I should change to fix my mess-up. Specifically, when I click my button it does not show any change in the text. Here's my code:

````
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: "Ame's Application", home: MyHomePage());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("App"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        ),
        body: TextInputWidget());
  }
}

class TextInputWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TextInputWidgetState createState() => _TextInputWidgetState();
}

class _TextInputWidgetState extends State<TextInputWidget> {
  int count = 0;

  increaseCount() {
    setState(() {
      count++;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("You have hit the button ${count} times"), SizedBox(height: 100,),
        FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: increaseCount(), child: Text("Click"))
      ]
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the reference of the function, not its return type so instead of:

```dart
FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: increaseCount(), child: Text("Click")
)
```

do this :

```dart
FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: increaseCount, child: Text("Click")
)
```

I also recommend you to set the return type of the `increaseCount` method to void (by default it is dynamic).

Comment: Thank You So Much!!

Comment: You're welcome ! If this fixed your problem, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes with your FloatingActionButton. `onPressed` requires a callback that is called when the button is tapped.

When your method has no parameter as is the case here, you can do:

```
FloatingActionButton(onPressed: increaseCount, child: Text("Click")),
```

But, in general, you would do:

```
FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () => increaseCount(), child: Text("Click")),
```

That would also allow you to define more complex method such as one that increments your counter by x:

```
FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () => increaseCount(x), child: Text("Click")),
```